How does framer-motion respond to the data attribute?
When combining Framermotion with some headless UI libraries like Radix Primitives, they use data attributes to represent states. It is easy to control animations for different data attributes through CSS animations. However, it seems challenging to achieve the same responsiveness to data attributes with Framermotion. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on this?
Framer Motion can read and animate CSS variables, for example, --radix-tooltip-content-available-height.
but how can Framer Motion respond to the change in data attributes when the state transitions from closed to open?
